# Fire App Builder: Amazon IAP Causes Freeze on Splash

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using the Amazon Fire App Builder to create a streaming app. It works great when testing. Submitted fine to Amazon, no issues.

However, when I enable IAP and follow the steps to add my subscription IAPs, it freezes on the splash screen. If I disable IAP it loads again. Seems to be an issue in the actual purchasing component.

Using Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.0 and the base Fire App Builder from the GIT.

```
E/SplashActivity: Failed to put data in cache for recipe
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.amazon.android.module.Module.getImpl(boolean)' on a null object reference
at com.amazon.android.contentbrowser.helper.PurchaseHelper.initializePurchaseSystem(PurchaseHelper.java:145)
at com.amazon.android.contentbrowser.helper.PurchaseHelper.<init>(PurchaseHelper.java:131)
at com.amazon.android.contentbrowser.ContentBrowser.onAllModulesLoaded(ContentBrowser.java:758)
at com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.SplashActivity$1.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:119)
at com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.SplashActivity$1.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:109)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

When I set the IAP to on, it freezes and throws this error. When I turn it back off it loads as expected with no issue.